# Name of math.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion

*This might be some duplicate (it should be) but I could not find a good reference..*

I believe there are some disputable references to our site math.stackexchange.com.

In particular, on 
https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex
our site is simply called Mathematics, giving me some slight shivering. However, I could not see any possibility to flag this - is it possible?

I think Math.SE is fine but not Mathematics - the site is not Mathematics. What do you think?

Comment: +1 Mathematics **doesn't** use MathJax to render LaTeX...

Comment: The site is not mathematics (with small m), but I don't see any problem calling the name of the site Mathematics (with big M).

Comment: I mean, are you going to complain that a rubber-like substance often used to make gloves cannot be run on a computer to typeset documents?

Comment: @WillieWong I can also see a difference between mathematics and Mathematics. But it is a little pretentious to call the site Mathematics don't you think.

Comment: @WillieWong To me *real* mathematics is hard, but Math.SE is more suited for understanding the basics and guidance through the subject.

Comment: @AD. I disagree that Math.SE is "more suited for understanding the basics and guidance through the subject". There are some pretty tough questions here, and some pretty complex answers...

Comment: @AD Mathematics (SE) should be the most comprehensive, most visited, and most valuable mathematics resource on the web. I don't see a reason to shoot for anything less.

Comment: @5PM I do.$ $    $ $

Comment: @5PM I am not saying that this is a bad site at all. The site can however not compete with math.sci.net or wikis like wikipedia - it does not have to compete with these or other sites either.

Comment: @user1729 Sure, there are harder mathematics here but is less common than "understanding the basics and guidance". (No offence :)

Comment: @AD. None take, and I mean none either. There may be more basic stuff here, but there is certainly enough of the hard stuff to keep you on your toes - I answered a question the other day which asked whether the torsion elements in a nilpotent group form a subgroup!...which isn't exactly your standard undergrad plug-and-chug proof...I would say that this site sits between MO and basically all of the other sites in the world (although I have only sampled a small number of these...but then you tend to hear of the good ones, don't you?).

Comment: @user1729 Agreed, I had a answer on estimating the Legendre function of the second kind, which is not a standard thing either. It is a pity it is no easy way to find the *interesting/deeper post/answers* so to say...

Comment: Physics does not seem to have an issue with their name, although they did have a discussion of the mildly entertaining URL `meta.physics.stackexchange.com`. SE sites in Biology, Chemistry, and Philosophy are named after their disciplines too. Why should Mathematics be an exceptions? // @AD. MathSciNet is off-limits to the majority of the world's population, and probably would not be of much help even if it were open. It is of value only to a very narrow slice of population.

Comment: Heh, the new [about page](http://math.stackexchange.com/about) says: "Mathematics is all about **getting answers**." This I don't like, because it's not clear if this statement is about the site or about the discipline it covers. (The LaTeX sentence is not so ambiguous.) If possible, I suggest using italics to indicated when *Mathematics* is being used as a proper noun.

Comment: @5PM "Mathematics is not a discussion forum..."

Comment: @5PM Should be "Mathematics is all about *discovering* answers."

Answer (score 13):

It looks like the site *is* called Mathematics to me:

[image]

Comment: Or perhaps MATHEMATICS?

Comment: Aye, tis *spelled* MATHEMATICS but *pronounced* [Haddocks' Eyes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haddocks'_Eyes).

Answer (score 5):

By the way: did you know that

> maths.stackexchange.com

will get you to MATHEMATICS as well?  For the benefit of those guys in the UK who never admitted that the US is superior in every way.

Comment: But there's no [stat.stackexchange.com](http://stat.stackexchange.com/) (:

Comment: How many questions can you ask about photocopying?