# Congrats, Math.StackExchange.com!

Tags: discussion, celebration

$\hskip2.7in$[image]

100.000 times people felt the need to ask someone for help, while facing a mathematical problem, where 
the motivation ranges from homework to pure mathematical curiosity.

Many of them (including me)
found at least one answer here at [Math.StackExchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/). There recently was a [comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8208/name-of-math-stackexchange-com#comment27532_8208) that summarises it nicely:

> Mathematics (SE) should be the most comprehensive, most visited, and most valuable mathematics resource on the web. I don't see a reason to shoot for anything less. [Amen]

So, thanks to all the people contributing in the past and good luck for the coming 100k...

Comment: which was the question 100,000?

Comment: @dwarandae [Continuity of analytic function implies convergence of power series?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/286119/19341), see the [Photo finish](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sslH5.jpg)...

Comment: Phew, that was a close call. (Thinking that the historical 100,000th question could the one by *gfg*.) The power series question is nice.

Comment: Aww, I was going to make this post... but I was out!

Comment: @draks: Wow, the $99999$-th question was asked two minutes earlier and had already been answered when the $100000$-th was asked :-)

Comment: @draks How do you know which was #100000?

Comment: @Mjd I stayed at home all day and waited until it popped up. How would you have done it? Isn't the displayed number of questions correct? If so and if I would have known that, I would/should have titled this post: The counter on the main site has six digits...

Comment: @draks I don't know how I would have done it; that's why I asked how you did it.

Comment: This is really a waste of time.



I recommend focusing on becoming an extraordinary expert instead of wasting time on silly things like number of questions and which questions to flag, is this appropriate. Spend lots of time using deliberate practice to learn lots of challenging, difficult things and later on solve cutting-edge problems.

Comment: Hear ye, hear ye! Let's see how far you get. I take the liberty to spend my time on what I want and focus on what I like. But there space for all kinds of opinions including yours...

Comment: Following Raindrop's comment perhaps we should post questions like "Celebrate Question $n$! Tell me what's so special about $n$." The answer might be $n$ is prime or $n$ is the order of a simple group. Stuff like that.

Comment: Conversely to Raindrop, I like the friendly supportive and cheerful spirit of the Math SE community who often celebrates its best members and other events of the site, as by this questions. On Physics there is only one closed (!) celebration post for [Lumo](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/4319) earning the first gold tag badge ever of the site (the very few other celebration posts got all deleted), whereas on Maths there is a whole bunch of meta questions having "congratulations" in the title. So I congratulate Maths SE too, and please keep up the good spirit ;-) ... Cheers

Answer (score 19, accepted):

$$\text{Yay!}$$

Vote this answer up to prevent the Community bot from bumping this question periodically.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, nobody mentioned this yet on meta: reaching 100,000 questions was mentioned on [SE podcast #42](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/02/podcast-42-2/) as a part of discussion about Math.SE. The discussion begins approximately at 25:30, and I think it may be of interest to users, especially in the context of recent threads such as [What is Math.SE?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9504/75064)